# Postman fails to return json from asmx service

Tags: c#, web, service

I have WebService and I'm using Postman to test it. But it keeps returning xml. I tried using `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json,UseHttpGet =false)]` in my WebMethod, also in postman the request is `http://localhost:port/folder/service.asmx/HelloWorld`. In the config File I Have

```
  <handlers>
  <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory,  System.Web.Extensions,  Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" resourceType="Unspecified" />
  </handlers>
```

It still doesn't work and Postman returns xml

Answer (score 1):

i'm posting the answer: I just uncommented:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add reference from nuget packager for "Newtonsoft.Json" so you will be able to return data in JSON format.

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataSet, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```